# How to forecast a 95% prediction interval for a variable?

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval

I have a data set containing the height of 1000 students for 4 years (one measurement for each student for each year), from 2011 to 2014.  I want to forecast the mean height for these students for the following year, 2015.  Crucially, I want the two-sided 95% prediction interval around that mean, that will contain 95% of the students' heights in 2015 (I'm not actually interested in the mean, only the interval around it).  The students should still be growing.

Comment: I have data for each student for each year, and yes, these students are still growing. I think two sided CI would be the best.

Comment: yes, the height is only measured once a year...

Comment: actually, i do not want the mean height, i only want to have an interval that contains 95% of the students's height...

Comment: Sorry, do you want an interval that contains 95% of student's mean heights for the year? Also, maybe I misunderstood, do you want a single prediction w/ a single CI for all student heights, or do you want a prediction for each student, w/ a 95% CI, & 95% of those turn out to cover that student's actual height?

Comment: I am thinking if I can get an interval that contains 95% of students' actual heights for 2015 which have not been measured yet, and it's just a single prediction with a single CI for all student heights.

Comment: OK, I think that should be clear enough. I edited your Q to include the info from the comments. Please ensure you are still OK with it. This isn't my specialty, but someone should be able to help you.